# Cronjob for a executing a single method of Java class

Tags: java, cron-task

Am a new bie to Java, Currently we are running a daily cronjob of executing a class (a struts2 web application project) which sends an email to two different team @ a specific time. The class includes two methods, one for sending email to sales team, and other for sending email to business team of the list of created keywords on the site that day. The requirement is to send an email to sales team @ a different time, and to business team to other team. So, can i write cron jobs by specifying the method name, so that only that specific method will be executed @ that time.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't call a method directly. But as a hack you can add your decision flag into the Execution Context's data map. In execute method check for this flag and call appropriate method.

Comment: Use something like Get and put method of [JobExecutionContext](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to your Main class, and use this parameter to call different method:

```
public class SelectMethod {
    public static void sendToSales() {
        System.out.println("Sending mail to sales team...");
    }

    public static void sendToOther() {
        System.out.println("Sending mail to other team...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("No required parameter passed\n"
                    + "Valid options: sales, other");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if ("sales".equals(args[0])) {
            sendToSales();
        } else if ("other".equals(args[0])) {
            sendToOther();
        }
    }
}
```

For sales team, run it with `java -cp . SelectMethod sales`; and for the other team, use `java -cp . SelectMethod other`.

Comment: Thanx for you answer Alexey, I tried the steps you have mentioned  $java -cp ExportWhiteListTerms.SelectMethod sales;  where ExportWhiteListTerms is the classname & using the SelectMethod as mentioned and sales is the argument. But its returning a ClassNotFoundException, Cannot find the main class: sales. Program will exit

Comment: @SangramAnand You should implement something similar, I gave you the code as an example. Of course you code does not have SelectMethod class. You should update your main class with the logic similar to this one. The sample invocations below just show how to run my example class which describes the idea. And `-cp` is the standard `java` parameter which tells JVM where to look for class files, most likely you already have the correct classpath.

Comment: Thanq so much Alexey for the detailed explanation. Your solutions works for my app.....  thanx once again.....:)